# Kion Zamenhof uzis anstataŭ «pluraj»?

Tags: history, language-evolution

Mi freŝe rimarkis, ke [laŭ PIV](http://vortaro.net/#plur), Zamenhof neniam uzis la vorton «pluraj». Plie [la vortaro de Louis de Beaufront](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=E589AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover) — aprobita de Zamenhof — ne enhavas ĝin. Mi ankaŭ ne povis trovi ĝin en la tekstoj de Zamenhof ĉe la [*Tekstaro*](http://tekstaro.com/).

Tio aspektas strange al mi, ĉar mi ĉiam kredis, ke «pluraj» estas Fundamenta vorto. Kvankam «pluraj» tute ne esprimas novan ideon kiel «komputilo», ĝi aperas ĉe la *Tekstaro* unuafoje en 1907 en *Kastelo de Prelongo*. Krom tio — kaj interese — la vorto «plura» aperis la sekvan jaron en la unuaj vortaroj de Ido. Laŭ PIV, «pluraj» oficialiĝis en Esperanto ne pli frue ol en la Kvara Oficiala Aldono (1929).

Kial «pluraj» aperis tiom malfrue en Esperanto, kaj kion Zamenhof uzis anstataŭ ĝi? Ĉu ĝia uzo en Ido — kiel pri «end» — estas la deveno de ĝia populareco en Esperanto? El tio rezultas **pluraj** demandoj de mi…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En PMEG [§8.2.4](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/unu-nombro_multe-nombro/uzado/specialaj_okazoj.html) aperas la komento:

> Zamenhof uzis ankaŭ ***pli-ol-unu*** (kun dividostrekoj) = *pluraj*. Tiam li uzis multe-nombron poste. Nuntempe oni neniam uzas *pli-ol-unu* tiumaniere, sed nur la vorton *pluraj*, kiu ne estas Zamenhofa (ĝi aperis nur en **1904**). Zamenhof uzis ankaŭ ***kelkaj*** kaj ***kelke*** + ***da-*** esprimo por “pluraj”, sed tian signifon *kelkaj* kaj *kelke* ne plu havas (kvankam kompreneble en la praktiko la diferenco inter “kelkaj” kaj “pluraj” estas tre subjektiva afero).

Mi ne scias precize, kiel oni enkondukis la vorton *pluraj* en Esperanton, sed Ido aperis en 1907, kaj la limo inter la komunumoj estis sufiĉe transirebla tiuepoke.

---

In PMEG [§8.2.4](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/unu-nombro_multe-nombro/uzado/specialaj_okazoj.html) appears the following remark (which I have translated):

> Zamenhof also used ***pli-ol-unu*** (with hyphens) = *pluraj*. After it he would use a plural noun. Nowadays one never uses *pli-ol-unu* in that way, only the word *pluraj*, which is not Zamenhofian (it appeared only in **1904**). Zamenhof also used ***kelkaj*** and ***kelke + da*** (expression) for *pluraj*, but *kelkaj* and *kelke* no longer have that meaning (although for obvious reasons in practice the difference between *kelkaj* and *pluraj* is a very subjective matter).

I do not know exactly how the word *pluraj* was introduced into Esperanto, but Ido appeared in 1907, and the boundary between the communities was permeable enough in those days.

Comment: Dankon pro via respondo! Strange, kiam mi serĉas la terminon "pli-ol-unu" en la Tekstaro, mi trovas nenian rezultaton. Tamen mi ja trovas "pli ol unu", sen streketo,  uzata plurajn fojojn de Zamenhof. Kial?

Comment: Mi ne certas; tamen, oni facile fidas la redaktadon de Wennergren, kaj ekzistas pluraj verkoj de Zamenhof kiuj ankoraŭ ne inkluziviĝas en la Tekstaro.